# File Download in PhoneGapp

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile app,where i want to download a file in memory card.I have following code for this,but its not working, can anyone suggest me why??

```
function dwnload()
    {    alert('in1'); 
     var fname=$("#filename").val();
     alert(fname);

      document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,gotFS,fail);


      }, false);   
     function gotFS(fileSystem){

             fileSystem.root.getfile(fname + '.csv',{create: true,exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
  alert('in gotFS');
     }
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
             fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        alert('in gotFileEntry');

    }
    function gotFileWriter(writer)
    {     alert('in gotFileWriter');
          var text_wrt=$("#filetxt").val();

          writer.write(text_wrt);
          writer.onwriteend= function(evt)
          {
             $('#status').text('File Was saved Successfully');
          }

    }
        function fail(error)
        {
             $('#status').text('File Save Error' +error.code);

        }
    }
```

and my html code for getting info.from user is as followa,once i submit following form then it calls above function,is there any error in my function for file download.

```
<h1>Example</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return dwnload();">
    File name:<input type="text" id="filename" name="filename" placeholder="Enter Name of File" />
    <div id="status"></div>
    <p><!-- <A HREF="#" onclick="dwnload();" data-ajax="false">Local File System</A></p> -->

    File Text:<input type="text" id="filetxt" name="filetxt" placeholder="Enter Something" />
   <BR> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" data-ajax="false"></>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you add the File plugin? Also, you can't say "it isn't working" - you have to say HOW it isn't working. Is there an error thrown in the console for example.

Comment: I have added File Plugin <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="File" intelxdk:value="intel.xdk.file"/> and Cordova plugin <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="File" intelxdk:value="org.apache.cordova.file" intelxdk:version="0.2.5"/>

And its not showing any error while trying on my samsung S4

Comment: No error- but where does it stop working? Have you stepped through the JS code?

Comment: in function gotFS it's not giving that alert,it's stoping over there

Comment: Function gotFS doesn't have an alert. Maybe add one before you do any more code? Also, you request 0 for the file size, maybe change that to 50 megs or some such.

Comment: Am getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined "

Comment: Here its checking for deviceready event but not getting LocalFileSystem access and giving above error on console

Comment: If i am missing any file or plugin of cordova API am not getting why this is not working,Help me